# What does koa-write do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, koa, koa2

My project uses the Koa framework, and I'm looking for a way to replace Express's res.write to stream large datasets into a csv.

Can I use [koa-write](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-write) to do this? Something like:

```
var write = require('koa-write');

router.get('/', (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.response.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    ctx.response.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=data.csv');
    write(ctx, "1,2,3,4,5\n");
});
```

I tried it but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried writing it like the example shows. ?     eg.  `ctx.body= PassThrough();` & `co(function *`  etc.?

Answer (score 0):

you can just create a Readable stream and assign to `ctx.body`

```js
const Koa = require("koa");
const { Readable } = require("stream");

const app = new Koa();
const s = new Readable();

app.use((ctx) => {
  if (ctx.request.url === "/") {
    ctx.body = s;
    s.push('"1,2,3,4,5\n');
    s.push("test test");
    s.push(null); // indicates end of the stream
  } else {
    ctx.throw(404);
  }
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Or if you already have a stream, just assign to body. otherwise, create a new Stream and push data to it. Terminate the stream with `null`